# Spring aspect support for repeatable annotation?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, aop, aspectj

I have created a java8's repeatable annotation and want create an aspect before the method containing the annotation is invoked. This seems to work when method is annotated once but fails to invoke when I have repeatable annotation. I am using aspectjrt version 1.8.6. Looks like aspect doesn't support repeatable annotations. Any workaround?

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MultiCacheEvicts
{
    MultiCacheEvict[] value();
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(MultiCacheEvicts.class)
public @interface MultiCacheEvict
{
    String value();

    String[] keyPrefix() default "";
}

@Aspect
public class MultiCacheEvictAdvice
{
    @Before("@annotation(multiCacheEvict)")
    public void cacheEvict(JoinPoint joinPoint, MultiCacheEvict 
    multiCacheEvict)
    { 
       //never gets invoked when repeatable annotation present on the method
    }
}

/**This works**/
@MultiCacheEvict(value = "default", keyPrefix ={"messageAttributes"})
public void purgeCache(Set<Long> userIds)

/**This doesn't works, advice never gets invoked**/
@MultiCacheEvict(value = "default", keyPrefix ={"messageAttributes"})
@MultiCacheEvict(value = "entity", keyPrefix ={"tagAttributes"})
public void purgeCache(Set<Long> userIds)
```

Comment: When you repeat the annotation, the method is actually annotated with the wrapping MultiCacheEvicts annotation.

Comment: Try getting the values as array to the annotation, that way you will have to specify the annotation only once.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks, that worked. @Before("@annotation(multiCacheEvicts)")
 public void cacheEvict(JoinPoint joinPoint, MultiCacheEvicts multiCacheEvicts)